# Requirement of constructor specialization

Tags: c++, templates

I try to specialize class where constructor have templated arguments, but I don't want to specialize constructors for every template specialization. For example:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
struct S{
    S( A _a, B _b ) : a(_a), b(_b){}
    A a;
    B b;
};
//Partial specialization
template<typename A>
struct S<A, int>{
};
int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    S<char, float> s0('1', 1.0);
    S<char, int> s1('1', 1);    //Compilation error
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation error:

```
main.cpp:13:24: error: no matching function for call to ‘S<char, int>::S(char, int)’
  S<char, int> s1('1', 1);
                        ^
main.cpp:13:24: note: candidates are:
main.cpp:9:8: note: S<char, int>::S()
 struct S<A, int>{
        ^
main.cpp:9:8: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
main.cpp:9:8: note: S<char, int>::S(const S<char, int>&)
main.cpp:9:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

Compilation will finished successfully if i append constructor:

```
S( A _a, int _b ) : a(_a), b(_b){}
```

to specialized class with all fields (a and b).

Why it is not work? Why constructor was not generated automatically?

Comment: You can use a common base class (template) + inheriting ctors as a workaround (in C++11).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each class template partial specialization is a separate template. You must provide definitions for each member of a class template partial specialization. Hence the compiler doesn't see the general class template's constructor i.e. you've to provide the constructor for the specilization too.

Since you're not providing any constructor for the specialization, it provides the default constructor which expects 0/no arguments. However since you provide 2 arguements the compiler is complaining.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know *what* you're trying to specialize, but as pointed out by @dyp, here is a way to avoid repeating members and constructors:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
struct Base
{
    Base(A a, B b) : a(a), b(b) { }
    A a;
    B b;
};

template<typename A, typename B>
struct S : Base<A, B>
{
    using Base<A, B>::Base;
    // extensions...
};

template<typename A>
struct S<A, int> : Base<A, int>
{
    using Base<A, int>::Base;
    // specialized extensions...
};
```

`using` base constructors is a C++11 feature. With this declaration you are bringing in *all* constructors of the base class. But you can add more in the derived class.

Comment: `using Base::Base;` should be `using Base<A, B>::Base;` and `using Base<A, int>::Base;`.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is using the specialized template class. Which doesn't have a constructor defined by you. So it uses the **default ones generated by the compiler**. i.e.

```
S<char, int>::S()  // default constructor
S<char, int>::S(const S<char, int>&)  // copy constructor
```

So you your specialized class right now is almost like this

```
template<typename A>
struct S {
    S();
    S(const S&);
};
```

What you need is something like

```
template<typename A>
struct S<A, int> {
    S(A a, int i) { .... }
};
```

---

If you *really really* want to avoid defining the constructors for each class just use some inheritance pattern like this

```
template<typename A>
struct S_int : public S<A, int> {};
```